# How can i import rl in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning

i'm working at a Machine Learning project and i need to import different libraries but i don't know why i'm not able to import rl. I solved the same problem for tensorflow editing the syntax but i cannot find  how to solve for rl.
This is the .py [![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import keras_tensor
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense,Flatten
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import adam_v2
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import generic_utils


from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy 
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
```

and the problem on the prompt is the following one.

```
Inteligence/ML_Car_Pole/gim.py", line 12, in <module>
    from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rl/agents/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .dqn import DQNAgent, NAFAgent, ContinuousDQNAgent
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rl/agents/dqn.py", line 8, in <module>
    from rl.core import Agent
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rl/core.py", line 8, in <module>
    from rl.callbacks import (
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rl/callbacks.py", line 12, in <module>
    from keras.utils.generic_utils import Progbar
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.utils.generic_utils'
```

but if i remore the three import related to rl the file run correctly

Comment: Just install the library, and make sure that you are running your code in the same virtual environment. If you are running the script from the terminal, activate the environment. If you are using IDE to run the code, choose the correct Python interpreter.

Comment: Please do **not** post screenshots - post the relevant code here as *text*; see how to create a [mre]

Comment: You need to use a version of keras that the rl library supports, which is not the latest version for sure.

Comment: Do you know which version is compatible? i tried a lot of different version but nothing

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you should probably reinstall rl, and if that fails, try `python3 -m pip install keras`. If both of these fail, it sounds like a problem with the package itself. Maybe you've installed a broken nightly build?

Comment: I already installed keras, keras-rl, keras-rl2, rl-agents,tensorflow. I tried what you had suggested but nothing...

Comment: have you tried downgrading rl?

Comment: I use another approach to not use the rl library in the end

Comment: @AlessiaVolpi what was your fix? I am trying the same thing and getting the same error.